# How to check message is duplicate using Text in Azure Service Bus Queue?

Tags: c#, azure, queue, message-queue, servicebus

> How to check message is duplicate using Text in Azure Service Bus Queue instead if MessageId

I tried MSDN CODE and properties like

```
  namespaceManager.CreateQueue(new QueueDescription(queueName) { RequiresDuplicateDetection = true, DuplicateDetectionHistoryTimeWindow = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10) });
            }
```

which checks duplicate based on `MessageId` in my Queue message gets inserted from various other sources.

I want to check duplicate using `Message Text`

Comment: probably bad idea, but the only way - by having unified algorithm for generating MessageId - i.e. some Hash of the content. MessageId property is String before all. Message deduplication only looks at MessageId property.

Comment: ok that make sense as there is nothing to check duplicate instead MessageId thanks